# Implementing a preferences dialog window in PyQt

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to use an interface I designed in Qt designer as a means of letting the user edit preferences for my program.

I am currently able to display the GUI I made by connecting the following function to the preferences menu option:

```
def preferences(self):

    preferences_dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    preferences_dialog.ui = Ui_Preferences()
    preferences_dialog.ui.setupUi(preferences_dialog)
    preferences_dialog.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
    preferences_dialog.exec_()
```

My question is this: what is a good way to implement this so that I can use the fields in the GUI to change values in my config file?

I also want to display the pre-existing values in the boxes before they are changed.

Should I make a new class that uses the above function as its __init__ method? I would imagine I might need a class that handles all of the processes for the window. Also, I am unsure of a good way to pass data between the file and the GUI without a bunch of specific code.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Use [QSettings](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsettings.html). Here's an example in PyQt5.

First, the main window's ui definition

```
# file ui_main.py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(584, 897)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 584, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuPreferences = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuPreferences.setObjectName("menuPreferences")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.setPreferencesAction = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.setPreferencesAction.setObjectName("setPreferencesAction")
        self.menuPreferences.addAction(self.setPreferencesAction)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuPreferences.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuPreferences.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Settings"))
        self.setPreferencesAction.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Preferences"))
```

and second, the preferences dialog ui definition:

```
# file ui_dialog.py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(508, 300)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 250, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.sl_value = QtWidgets.QSlider(Dialog)
        self.sl_value.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 120, 161, 31))
        self.sl_value.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.sl_value.setObjectName("sl_value")
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
```

The `MainWindow` keeps track of the configuration in a `QSettings` object, which is uniquely defined (and accessed) using the `application` and `company` strings fed into its constructor.

```
# file main.py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.settings = QSettings(COMPANY_NAME, APPLICATION_NAME)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

when the preferences dialog box is triggered, the `settings` are loaded and passed along to the `PreferencesDialog`. If the Dialog returns successfully, the new settings are saved and written to storage using `del`

```
    @pyqtSlot(bool)
    def on_setPreferencesAction_triggered(self, triggered):
        settings = self.settings
        default_config_value = settings.value(CONFIG_KEY_1, defaultValue=None, type=str)

        preference_dialog = PreferencesDialog(default_config_value=default_config_value, parent=self)
        if preference_dialog.exec():
            settings.setValue(CONFIG_KEY_1, preference_dialog.preferences[CONFIG_KEY_1])

            # this writes the settings to storage
            del settings
```

The `PreferencesDialog` constructor sets the values according to the parameters it receives, and a a `pyqtSlot` is attached to the appropriate `signal` to save the values in a dictionary.

To run the demo:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: how does one access the settings in the app?